# Matlab ode45 takes tool long and steps in function delet(h)

Tags: matlab

I have a problem with ode45. I've defined a function and trying to solve it by ode, but when i run it, it takes so long. I tried to display the "t" input in my function and it showed time step was 10^-8 ! [I do not get any error from ode45]
So i put a breakpoint at the end of my function, and after I Step once, it goes to sym.m file and calls Function delet(h)

```
function dxr=Dynfun(t,x)
...
dxr=[A;B]
```

after Step it goes to

```
function delete(h)
    if builtin('numel',h)==1 && inmem('-isloaded','mupadmex') && builtin('numel',h.s)==1 && ~isa(h.s,'maplesym')
        mupadmex(h.s,1);
    end
    end
```

and that's what makes it too long, because it goes in a loop in there.
what's the problem?! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's a "stiff" problem to me. I would recommend using a solver that is designed for stiff problems.  I would also recommend trying a fixed step solver at a small step size ~ 0.001 and see what the output looks like.  If you are breaking in `sym.m`, sounds like you've some some symbolic logic going on in there.  Is there a way you could take your symbolic expression and convert it to a [matlab script](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html)?

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by macduff, your problem could be stiff. Try `ode15s` (which is designed for stiff problems) and see if the stepsize still decreases to unacceptably low values.

If that is indeed the case, then your problem might contain a singularity for the initial values you give it. If your problem has dimensions lower than 3, you can define a small `event` function to get insight into the values at each step, and plot them to see if there is indeed something problematic going on.

Then -- do you really need symbolic math? The philosophy behind that is that it's easier to read for humans, which makes it terrible to deal with for computers :) If you can transform it into something non-symbolic, please do -- this will noticeably increase performance.

Also, more a word of advice, `delete` is also Matlab builtin function. It is generally a bad idea to name your functions after Matlab buitins -- it's confusing, and can cause a lot of overhead while Matlab is deciding which one to use.